# How to get last 10 minutes of logs from remote host

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, sed, grep

I'm trying to get the last `x` minutes of logs from `/var/log/maillog` from a remote host (I'm using this script within icinga2) but having no luck.

I have tried a few combinations of awk, sed, and grep but none have seemed to work. I thought it was an issue with double quotes vs single quotes but I played around with them and nothing helped.

```
host=$1
LOG_FILE=/var/log/maillog

hour_segment=$(ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' myUser@${host} 2>/dev/null "sed -n "/^$(date --date='10 minutes ago' '+%b %_d %H:%M')/,\$p" ${LOG_FILE}")

echo "${hour_segment}"
```

When running the script with bash -x, I get the following output:

```
bash -x ./myScript.sh host.domain
+ host=host.domain
+ readonly STATE_OK=0
+ STATE_OK=0
+ readonly STATE_WARN=1
+ STATE_WARN=1
+ LOG_FILE=/var/log/maillog
+++ date '--date=10 minutes ago' '+%b %_d %H:%M'
++ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myUser@host.domain 'sed -n /^Jan' 8 '12:56/,$p /var/log/maillog'
+ hour_segment=
+ echo ''
```

Maillog log file output. I'd like `$hour_segment` to look like the below output also so I can apply filters to it:

```
head -n 5 /var/log/maillog
Jan  6 04:03:36 hostname imapd: Disconnected, ip=[ip_address], time=5
Jan  6 04:03:36 hostname postfix/smtpd[9501]: warning: unknown[ip_address]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jan  6 04:03:37 hostname imapd: Disconnected, ip=[ip_address], time=5
Jan  6 04:03:37 hostname postfix/smtpd[7812]: warning: unknown[ip_address]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jan  6 04:03:37 hostname postfix/smtpd[7812]: disconnect from unknown[ip_address]
```

Comment: Please post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: I've added the maillog output to the post.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this format: A date of the form `Jan  6 04:03:36` is not sortable as `Feb 29 < Jan 6` and there is no year, which mean that it is difficult to decide which January you need. The one of 2019 or the one from 1919. ...

Comment: I've taken a look at the maillogs that I have to work with and they are rotated.  Would it be safe to say that there would only ever be '1' January in a giving log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk's time functions:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    m["Jan"]=1               # convert month abbreviations to numbers 
    # fill in the rest       # fill in the rest of the months
    m["Dec"]=12
    nowy=strftime("%Y")      # assume current year, deal with Dec/Jan below
    nowm=strftime("%b")      # get the month, see above comment
    nows=strftime("%s")      # current epoch time
}
{                            # below we for datespec for mktime
    dt=(nowm=="Jan" && $1=="Dec"?nowy-1:nowy) " " m[$1] " " $2 " " gensub(/:/," ","g",$3)
    if(mktime(dt)>=nows-600) # if timestamp is less than 600 secs away
        print                # print it
}' file
```

Current year is assumed. If it's January and log has Dec we subtract one year from `mktime`'s datespec: `(nowm=="Jan" && $1=="Dec"?nowy-1:nowy)`. Datespec: `Jan  6 04:03:37` -> `2019 1 6 04 03 37` and for comparison in epoch form: `1546740217`.

**Edit**: As no one implemeted my specs in the comments I'll do it myself. `tac` outputs file in reverse and the awk prints records while they are in given time frame (`t`-now or future) and exits once it meets a date outside of the time frame:

```
$ tac file | awk -v t=600 '   # time in seconds go here
BEGIN {
    m["Jan"]=1
    # add more months
    m["Dec"]=12
    nowy=strftime("%Y")
    nowm=strftime("%b")
    nows=strftime("%s")
} {
    dt=(nowm=="Jan" && $1=="Dec"?nowy-1:nowy) " " m[$1] " " $2 " " gensub(/:/," ","g",$3)
    if(mktime(dt)<nows-t)     # this changed some
        exit                
    else 
        print
}'
```

Comment: Very nice! Just to be clear, this will only work if your logfile has maximum 1 year of data.

Comment: Yeah. The correct way would be to use `tac` to go backwards the log and exit once there is a timestamp older than 10 minutes. I'll leave this spec here for someone to actually implement it.

Comment: Thanks!  Not having the year seems to be a real pain.  I'll give this a try, see what happens :)

Comment: Updated with another version.

Answer (score 2):

Coming up with a robust solution that will work 100% bulletproof is very hard since we are missing the most crucial information, the **year**.

Imagine you want the last 10 minutes of available data on *March 01 2020* at *00:05:00*. This is a bit annoying since *February 29 2020* exists. But in 2019, it does not.

I present here an ugly solution that only looks at the third field (the time) and I will make the following assumptions:

- The log-file is sorted by time
- There is at least one log every single day!

Under these conditions we can keep track of a *sliding window* starting from the first available time.

If you safe the following in an file `extractLastLog.awk`

```
{ t=substr($3,1,2)*3600 + substr($3,4,2)*60 + substr($3,7,2) + offset}
(t < to) { t+=86400; offset+=86400 }
{ to = t }
(NR==1) { startTime = t; startIndex = NR }
{ a[NR]=$0; b[NR]=t }
{ while ( startTime+timeSpan*60 <= t ) { 
      delete a[startIndex]
      delete b[startIndex]
      startIndex++; startTime=b[startIndex]
  }
}
END { for(i=startIndex; i<=NR; ++i) print a[i] }
```

then you can extract the last 23 minutes in the following way:

```
awk -f extractLastLog.awk -v timeSpan=23 logfile.log
```

The second condition I gave (*There is at least one log every single day!*) is needed not to have messed up results. In the above code, I compute the time fairly simple, `HH*3600 + MM*60 + SS + offset`. But I make the statement that if the current time is smaller than the previous time, it implies we are on a different day hence we update the offset with 86400 seconds. So if you have two entries like:

```
Jan 09 12:01:02 xxx 
Jan 10 12:01:01 xxx
```

it will work, but this

```
Jan 09 12:01:00 xxx 
Jan 10 12:01:01 xxx
```

will not work. It will not realize the day changed. Other cases that will fail are:

```
Jan 08 12:01:02 xxx 
Jan 10 12:01:01 xxx
```

as it does not know that it jumped two days. Corrections for this are not easy due to the months (all thanks to leap years).

As I said, it's ugly, but might work.

Comment: Love the final comment _it's ugly, but might work_. :D

Comment: Nice one!  Another option to try, thanks for the input kvantour!